# Freenas VS commercial NAS: what hardware would you reccomand?

Tags: hard-disk, server, raid-controller, nas

I need to build a Raid 5 NAS system mainly for storage.

I am considering to use FreeNas server: what hardware would you recommend for a system with 5 HDD (total 3.5TB)?

I also have a pc sitting in my garage, not too old (quadcore, 8Gb ram, 120Gb SSD) but which has only three Sata access, so looking online I found this card: **SYBA SY-PCI40010 PCI SATA II (3.0 Gb/s) RAID Controller Card** (here the [link](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816124028&cm_re=raid_controller_card-_-16-124-028-_-Product)) Do you think is posisble for me to connect three extra HDD to this card and create a Raid 5 system with a total of five or six HDD?

Thanks

Comment: Hi there! I've put this question on hold because it's asking about using existing hardware and software to create a system, rather than asking for a recommendation of hardware. This site doesn't deal with such questions. However, addressing your actual problem - if you asked for a recommendation of a cheap NAS system, compatible with your systems, with X storage, bonus points for compatibility with your existing stuff, that would be on-topic. Remember to specify as much as you can, though.

Comment: ops, sorry for the confusion. I posted something similar on askubuntu and i was told it was more appropriate for this site (reason why i deleted my original post from askubuntu). the thing is that i'm feeling a little bit lost because i am not sure where to get minimal help for this issue :(

Comment: I'm sorry you've been thrown around the network a bit - we're having a bit of trouble communicating what's OK here to other sites. You *may* be able to get help on [su], though don't hold me to that and read their [help center](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) first. If you can rephrase this to ask us what hardware we'd recommend for this task, then it'll be OK here.